# I am trying to use properties from a csv file, but I'm receiving an error message that a property doesn't exist, but it does and I checked it

Tags: powershell, csv, for-loop, import-csv

Here is what I have so far:

A csv file named C:\TEMP\AIST2330TP04\SampleEnrollees.csv that contains the following information:

```
OrgDefinedId,Username,LastName,FirstName,Email,Section
1,tuser,User,Test,tuser@mymail.com,AIST2330
2,duser,User,Demo,duser@mymail.com,AIST2330
3,istudent,Student,Ima,istudent@mymail.com,AIST2330
4,ustudent,Student,Ura,ustudent@mymail.com,AIST2330
5,cfarquar,Farquar,Clyde,cfarquar@mymail.com,AIST2330
```

And my code that is parameterized and takes certain information and outputs text files:

```
#this parameter is a requirement    
param(
[string]$WorkDir = 'C:\Users\cryanderson\Documents'
)
#this is just so that the process can be run multiple times without creating multiple folders and files
Remove-Item 'DemoFiles' -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
mkdir 'DemoFiles'
$csv=Import-Csv C:\TEMP\AIST2330TP04\SampleEnrollees.csv
#I want to make sure I am using existing properties, so I display them here
echo $csv
$csv | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 
'Name'
#The loop that I am having issues with
ForEach($line in $csv)`
{
$username = $_.Username,`
$lastname = $_.LastName,`
$firstname = $_.FirstName,`
$text = "Generated for $firstname $lastname by cryanderson.",`
$text |Out-File 
"C:\Users\cryanderson\Documents\DemoFiles\${username}Stuff.txt"
}
```

When I run it, the following happens, without any files being created:

```
PS C:\Users\cryanderson\documents> 
C:\Users\cryanderson\Documents\CreateDemoFiles.ps1


    Directory: C:\Users\cryanderson\documents


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                  

----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                  

d-----        3/11/2018   8:54 PM                DemoFiles                                                                                             

OrgDefinedId : 1
Username     : tuser
LastName     : User
FirstName    : Test
Email        : tuser@mymail.com
Section      : AIST2330


OrgDefinedId : 2
Username     : duser
LastName     : User
FirstName    : Demo
Email        : duser@mymail.com
Section      : AIST2330


OrgDefinedId : 3
Username     : istudent
LastName     : Student
FirstName    : Ima
Email        : istudent@mymail.com
Section      : AIST2330


OrgDefinedId : 4
Username     : ustudent
LastName     : Student
FirstName    : Ura
Email        : ustudent@mymail.com
Section      : AIST2330


OrgDefinedId : 5
Username     : cfarquar
LastName     : Farquar
FirstName    : Clyde
Email        : cfarquar@mymail.com
Section      : AIST2330

Email
FirstName
LastName
OrgDefinedId
Section
Username

#This error message is repeated for all 5 users listed
The property 'FirstName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\cryanderson\Documents\CreateDemoFiles.ps1:14 char:14
+ $firstname = $_.FirstName,`
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

I think there is an issue with my for loop, but I cannot figure it out. Help please?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$line.FirstName` instead of `$_.FirstName`? I would expect you even get more errors than that.

Comment: Adding line worked, but only with one of the lines. It created 2 files, one named Stuff with and no variable information, and the other is perfect with cfarquarStuff.txt and it says "Generated for Clyde Farquar by cryanderson."  So t seems to not run for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I believe your problem is the use of `$_`, this will access the current item in the pipeline, which you're regarding as the item in your loop. However, since you're assigning each item `$line in $csv` it is not being placed in the pipeline, and throughout all your code in the loop, you should be accessing properties of your `$line` variable

EDIT: Also keep in mind what ` is doing. Having an extra one of those is going to break a line of code, and create some unexpected results

You are basically saying this is all one line:

`$username = $_.Username, $lastname = $_.LastName, $firstname = $_.FirstName, $text = "Generated for $firstname $lastname by cryanderson.", $text |Out-File "C:\Users\cryanderson\Documents\DemoFiles\${username}Stuff.txt"`

Also, With this code, Out-File would give a null path error, so I assume you simply fixed that issue.

I believe the reason you are getting weird $username values is because the code is all getting executed at once, and the variables are not getting assigned before `Out-File` is ran. So the first loop it is being assigned as null, and the second loop it will have the previously assigned value in it. Not sure why it would only run twice, hopefully something someone else can answer.

Comment: Editing $_ . to $line. worked, but only with one of the lines. It created 2 files, one named Stuff with and no variable information, and the other is perfect with cfarquarStuff.txt and it says "Generated for Clyde Farquar by cryanderson." So it seems to not run for each line.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using ` at the end of each line? This is just like using `+` in some other languages, or basically "the next line of code is a continuation of this line". Try taking another look at those

Comment: Should probably also add that if you are wanting to do multiple commands on one line, the proper seperator is `;`

Comment: That was it! So I was using the escape stroke because when I wrote it initially, the code within the loop's brackets was not being included properly. Removing those fixed everything. Thank you guys!